# Semiconductors: Hole current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

...And then suddenly It came in my book, Hole current is also there in semiconductors and I know it.  But there's a little thing that's confusing me. Is this hole current temporary? Yes, according to me. Isn't it? What if all the holes generated travels up to the negative potential. What after that? As they are atoms(positively charged). They can't move outside the material and go in the circuit like electrons are doing. So, what happens to those positively charged atoms at the negative potential? Do they remains there? Forever?

There's a second little doubt too, I've read about *recombination process in semiconductors*. So, when the electrons are moving towards positive potential and holes towards negative. Then do the **recombinations** occur? Do electrons go back into the holes?

*These are two doubts i'm having in the section **intrinsic semiconductors** of my book. Please clear these doubts. Thank you so much!*

> **Note: I'm a school student studying in class 12. So, please answer it according to the level of grade 12 school students.**

Comment: Good question. But holes are not atoms, they are unoccupied states in the valence band. Connections to a metal can be a problem (Schottky barriers) but you are right, this is where recombination can take place. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal%E2%80%93semiconductor_junction

Comment: thanks sir, BUT I DIDN'T GET MY ANSWER....PHEW!

Answer (score 1):

> holes are not atoms, they are unoccupied states in the valence band. Connections to a metal can be a problem (Schottky barriers) but you are right, this is where recombination can take place

this is the answer to your question! Holes are not positively charged atoms. They are unoccupied positions in the electron shell. They behave like free positive charges. The "current" through them is just the movement of the electrons from neighbouring particles and causing another hole to form behind them. I would recommend you to go back to your textbook and refer to it. If you are Indian, the NCERT tb provides adequate explanation of this concept.

Comment: And i had posted it after referring NCERT!

Comment: so what is your doubt then? can you be more precise

Comment: I had cleared it already then, this post is too old for me! I was then completing unit 9 Semiconductors of my class 12....now full syllabus is completed and revision is going on..and im having my final board exam on 7 march 2018

Comment: oh... mine's on 20th feb lol (ISC), all the best

Comment: Omg! it's too near..i mean best of luck... I hope you are studying now! Which unit?....I'm too excited!

Comment: haha I'm doing transistors right now, tried the rote learn method earlier for it but keep forgetting. I'm now trying to wrap my head around what exactly I don't understand

Comment: excited for the exam? hahaha seriously??

Answer (score 0):

Holes are really electrons that are jumping from one vacant pkace to another. So, just like the electron current, at one terminal they are injected into the semiconductor, and at the other taken away by the power source. In some fields the two terminals are aptly called *source* and *drain/sink* - using the analongy with flowing water.

Answer (score 0):

To understand it, one needs to know about valence level and conduction level.
Valence level is a level where are "placed" electrons with the ability to get some energy and move to other levels.
Conduction level is the level which can be reached by electrons by getting energy from the outside.

When electrons get to the conduction level, they can move in this level. This movement is called "current".

But the electron from valence level left an atom. Atom is neutral, electron is negative. If the negative charge left, the atom is no longer neutral - it's positive after being left by electron. And this place after electron, is called a "hole".

Also, positive charge attracts negative one, so there will be movement of electrons. jumping to the hole and the jumping to the next one, newly created by other electron which just left other atom.
The thing that moves is electron, not hole, but place where the hole appears guides electron movement. This electron movement is in the valence level.